# How to capture/ignore ESC during the execution of dialog?

Tags: linux, escape-characters, dialog

Currently playing around with the dialog command and I have noticed that when I press Shift-Tab or press ESC, the execution immediately exits and I am back on the command prompt. Since this is not a signal, I can't trap and discard it, so how would I "trap"/capture this escape and discard it so that the only way to exit the dialog is through whatever widget/box I set up?

Note: I have already researched why the combination of Shift and Tab triggers the escape. It is not a single keystroke and the solutions I have found only work when the input expected is a single keyboard stroke. Dialog does not have documentation on this topic and anything outside of its man page seems to be lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>*Shift*</kbd>+<kbd>*Tab*</kbd> is usually a back-tab on terminals that you are likely to use.

The manual page section [*KEY BINDINGS*](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html#h2-KEY-BINDINGS) comments that dialog's key bindings can be *curses keys*

> It may be any of the names derived from **`curses.h`**, e.g., "**HELP**" from
> "**KEY_HELP**".

and in the section [Built-in Bindings](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html#h3-Built-in-Bindings) explains that the **`--trace`** option can be used to show the built-in bindings:

> This  manual  page  does not list the key bindings for each widget, because that detailed information can be obtained by running ***`dialog`***.   If
> you have set the **`--trace`** option, ***`dialog`*** writes the key-binding information for each widget as it is registered.

As an example, it shows how to bind *TAB* and *BTAB* (the name derived from curses `KEY_BTAB`):

```
          bindkey formfield TAB  form_NEXT
          bindkey formbox   TAB  form_NEXT
          bindkey formfield BTAB form_prev
          bindkey formbox   BTAB form_prev
```

`KEY_BTAB` (see [getch](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Predefined-key-codes) manual page) is the *back-tab* key.

In [terminfo](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Predefined-Capabilities), that is named `kcbt`:

```
     key_btab                    kcbt      kB     back-tab key
```

You can see a terminal description using [`infocmp`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/infocmp.1m.html).

If you happen to have set TERM to a terminal description which does not define `kcbt`, then (because it is usually an *escape sequence*), curses will not recognize it, and will pass the individual bytes to the application (dialog).  dialog uses the ASCII escape character (**`ESC`**) to cancel the current widget.  A shell script can check for this by inspecting the exit-status.  The [ENVIRONMENT](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html#h2-ENVIRONMENT) section documents environment variables which can be used to customize the exit-status:

> Define any of these variables to change the exit code on
> ***Cancel***  (1), ***error*** (-1), ***`ESC`*** (255), ***Extra*** (3), ***Help*** (2),
> ***Help with --item-help*** (2), or ***OK***  (0).   Normally  shell
> scripts cannot distinguish between -1 and 255.

Comment: This actually explains a lot of things that were not making a lot of sense in that man page. After investigating the terminfo and tracing how dialog was processing the back-tab (not as a curses key, although kcbt is defined in terminfo, but rather passing the bytes to dialog), I decided to write the executions of dialog in a loop, checking for exit code 255 and re-executing the same command-arguments until the exit code is not 255 and then according to the exit code how it would proceed.